# T4MVC and HTTPS not showing up in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, ssl, https, t4mvc

Im a bit confused but my URLs being rendered with `T4MVC` on my local `IIS Express` contain HTTPS in the URL.  On our staging server the URL being rendered contains HTTP but are using the same code like below?  Does anyone know why?

```
<a href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: '@Url.GetSearchResultsUrl(MVC.ManageArea.DistrictAdmins.DistrictAdmin())&id=' + Id }">View</a>

public static string GetSearchResultsUrl(this UrlHelper urlHelper, ActionResult actionResult)
        {
            return urlHelper.ActionAbsolute(actionResult.AddRouteValue(Config.ViewData.SearchResults, true));
        }
public static string ActionAbsolute(this UrlHelper urlHelper, ActionResult result) {
            return string.Format("{0}{1}",urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority),
                urlHelper.RouteUrl(result.GetRouteValueDictionary()));
```

**UPDATE**

I just found out a F5 load balancer is doing the redirect from http to https using a 302 redirect.
            }

Answer (score 0):

There were some recent changes to automatically use https, but that should only happen if you're using the [RequireHttps] attributes. Do you know if you're using that?

See the [change log](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_History) for details. This was added in 2.8.0/2.8.1.

Search for 'ActionUrlHttps' in t4mvc.tt to see the relevant code.

Comment: urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) is grabbing http, not https on a secure page for some reason.

Comment: I guess so, not sure.  That method is in the T4MVC extensions.

Comment: To isolate, maybe try to see what Request.Url evaluates to outside of T4MVC. It sounds like that's getting an http URL.

Comment: Easier said then done.  This is on a staging server I dont have access too.